# Bind Paste Function to JQuery Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqte

Can anybody tell me why I get no output from this function?

```
$('.jqte_editor').bind('paste', function() {
    console.log("hi")
});
```

I have also tried `on(`

```
$('.jqte_editor').on('paste', function() {
    console.log("hi")
});
```

HTML:

`<textarea class="jqte" style="margin-bottom: -20px;" rows="50" cols="50" name="body" id="body"></textarea>`

Rendered HTML:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is it possible that you are binding the event before the   editor's html is created? Can you replicate this on a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's very likely that what @cviejo has mentioned in his comment is the cause of the issue here. That is, the bind statement is being executed before the HTML div is created in the DOM.

Comment: Functions are inside of `$(window).load(function () {`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

$(document).on("paste", ".jqte_editor", function(e) {

```
//Do here what you want.
```

});